# How to Delete Multiple rows by selecting checkBox using MVC 4 Webgrid wihtout Using Begin form

Tags: javascript, html, razor, model-view-controller

> > **Hi I am Currently Working On MVC Razor. here is the scenario. can
> >     anyone have a solution?**
> >         How to Delete Multiple rows by selecting checkBox using MVC 4 Webgrid wihtout Using Begin form
> >
> > Index.cshtml
> >         
> >           
> >                         Add
> >                         Edit
> >
> > ```
> > //Here if i click on Delete Link i need to get Selected rows from WEbgrid ? and should delete 
> >                   <th><a href="#" title="Delete" id="DeleteSelectedChkbx" >Delete</a></th> 
> >
> >             </tr>
> > </div>
> > ```
>
> ```
>  @using (@Html.BeginForm("Index", "Users", FormMethod.Post)) {
> @(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.user)
> .Name("GroupsGrid")
>  //.Events(events => events.Change("onChangenow").DataBound("onDataBound").DataBinding("onDataBinding"))
> .Columns(columns =>
> {
>     columns.Template(@<text></text>).ClientTemplate("<input type='checkbox' id='#= ID#,#= Name#' class='grid_checkbox'/>")
>     .HeaderTemplate("<input type='checkbox' id='selectall'/>").Width(50);
>     columns.Bound(p => p.ID).Hidden(true);
>     columns.Bound(p => p.Name).Title("Name");
> })
> //.Selectable(selectable => selectable.Mode(GridSelectionMode.Multiple))
> //.Navigatable()
> .Sortable()
> .Scrollable(src => src.Height("650px"))
> .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
>     .Ajax()
>     .PageSize(20)
>     //.Read(read => read.Action("Jobs_Read", "Jobs").Data("JobsReadData"))
>     )
> .Resizable(resize => resize.Columns(true))
>
> )        }
> ```
>
> $(function () {
>               // add multiple select / deselect functionality
>               $("#selectall").click(function () {
>                   var checkAll = $("#selectall").prop('checked');
>                   if (checkAll) {
>                       $(".grid_checkbox").prop("checked", true);
>                   } else {
>                       $(".grid_checkbox").prop("checked", false);
>                   }
>               });
>
> ```
>         // if all checkbox are selected, check the selectall checkbox and vice versa
>         $(".grid_checkbox").click(function () {
>             if ($(".grid_checkbox").length == $(".grid_checkbox:checked").length) {
>                 $("#selectall").prop("checked", true);
>             } else {
>                 $("#selectall").prop("checked", false);
>             }
>         });
>     });    
> </script>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Delete
$("#DeleteSelectedChkbx").click(function () {
    var checkGridSelection = "";
    var selected = $(".grid_checkbox:checked").map(function () {
        checkGridSelection = "Selected";
        return this.id;
    }).get();

    if (checkGridSelection == "Selected") {
        var r = confirm("The selected group(s) will be deleted. Do you want to continue?");
        if (r == true) {
            var selectedIds = selected.join(";");
            //alert(selectedIds);
            var serviceURL = '/Groups/DeleteGroups';
            $.ajax({
                type: 'Post',
                cache: false,
                url: serviceURL,
                data: { selectedIds: selectedIds },
                //dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    //alert("delete success");
                }
            });
        }
    }
    window.location.href = '/Groups';
});
```